# HAProxy http-request deny and SNI

Tags: haproxy, sni

I have the following configuration:

```
global
  demon
  maxconn 256
  log / dev / log local0 debug

defaults
  option httplog
  timeout connect 5000ms
  timeout client 50000ms
  timeout server 50000ms

frontend http_in
  mode tcp
  bind *: 80
  bind *: 443

tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
  acl sslv3 req.ssl_ver 3
  tcp-request content reject if sslv3
  tcp-request content accept if {req_ssl_hello_type 1}
  
  acl test1 req_ssl_sni -i test1.domain.abc
  acl test2 req_ssl_sni -i test2.domain.abc

  use_backend Test1_ssl if test1
  use_backend Test2_ssl if test2

backend Test1_ssl
  mode tcp
  stick-table type binary len 32 size 30k expire 30m
  
  acl clienthello req_ssl_hello_type 1
  acl serverhello req_ssl_hello_type 2

`# use tcp content accepts to detects ssl client and server hello.`

tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
  tcp-request content accept if clienthello

  # no timeout on response inspect delay by default.
  tcp-response content accept if serverhello

  stick on payload_lv (43,1) if clienthello

  # Learn on response if server hello.
  stick store-response payload_lv (43,1) if serverhello

  option ssl-hello-chk
  server Test1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443

backend Test2_ssl
  mode tcp
  stick-table type binary len 32 size 30k expire 30m

  acl clienthello req_ssl_hello_type 1
  acl serverhello req_ssl_hello_type 2

  # use tcp content accept to detects ssl client and server hello.
  tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
  tcp-request content accept if clienthello

  # no timeout on response inspect delay by default.
  tcp-response content accept if serverhello

  stick on payload_lv (43,1) if clienthello

  #Learn on response if server hello.
  stick store-response payload_lv (43,1) if serverhello

  option ssl-hello-chk
  server Test2 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443
```

Now I want the function for Test1_ssl that all requests are automatically forwarded to the path / forwarding path.

After I couldn't find any functions for this in haproxy, I tried "http-request deny" to forbid all requests to other paths except path / forwarding path.

For this I used the following:

```
acl is_static path -i -m beg / forwarding path
http request deny if is_static
```

No matter where I use this in my code, it has no effect - all paths are always accessible.

My guess is that it's up to SNI. Does anyone know if there is a way to implement this in my configuration?

Many Thanks

Comment: You use `TCP` mode, so HTTP related functions are unlikely to work. Especially with SSL encrypted traffic, which your configuration has no way to decipher. Switch to `HTTP` mode and terminating SSL traffic on haproxy, so it has a chance to inspect your HTTP traffic.